# Get QgsField alias in QGIS Python

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

In QGIS Python, how to get alias of field. In class QgsField, i can not find method to do this.

```
lay = iface.activeLayer()
provider = lay.dataProvider()
fields = provider.getFields()

for field in fields:
    print field.[SOMETHING]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For QGIS v3.x:

### If you've got a `QgsVectorLayer` object

You can get a Python dictionary of aliases calling:

```
   layer.attributeAliases()
```

Which gives you something like:

```
   {'type': 'Municipality Type', 'name': 'Municipality Name', ...}
```

If you have a specific field index and you only want to get its alias, you can use:

```
   layer.attributeAlias( field_index )
```

Which gives you something like:

```
   'Municipality Name'
```

### If you've got a `QgsFields` object

*(As explained in the answer by @signedav)*

You can get a Python list of aliases calling:

```
   aliases = [field.alias() for field in layer_fields]
```

Which gives you something like:

```
   ['Municipality Type', 'Municipality Name', ...]
```

If you have a specific field index and you only want to get its alias, you can use:

```
   layer_fields.field( field_index ).alias()
```

Which gives you something like:

```
   'Municipality Name'
```

Answer (score 3):

It's supported meanwhile (since 3.0):

```
lay = iface.activeLayer()
field_aliases = [field.alias() for field in lay.fields()]
```

https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Field/QgsField.html#qgis.core.QgsField.alias